# Libreoffice Page Numbering - Total pages and Section pages simultaneously

Tags: libreoffice-writer, page-numbers

I'm writing a document that has 10 chapters. My readers consume their content at speed X pages/time-unit.  I would like for them to be able to estimate when they will finish my entire document (total-pages/reading-speed), as well as make similar estimates about the respective sections ({ SECTIONPAGES }/reading-speed).

Does LibreOffice Writer have this dual page-numbering facility?

Comment: I haven't done anything this fancy, but I believe you can do it. Most common elements that might go in a header or footer are available as built-in fields (Insert | Field), and you can combine multiple fields. That includes some time fields. You can also define variables and do calculations in Writer, and create macros (might be needed for updating times and calculations on demand). You should be able to calculate values for elapsed time and rates, and I think you can includes fields in your formulas. It looks like the components and features needed to accomplish what you want to do are there.

Comment: fixer1234 Thanks *very* much for this reply.  Are there some "advanced tutorials" that I can access to learn this sort of thing?

Comment: I'm not aware of any tutorials, but I'll keep my eye out.  The LibreOffice help topics more or less cover the basics, but as separate topics.  The last time I did this general kind of thing was in MS Office.  Word help is extensive and I figured it out from that.  I only checked the LO features and it looks like the needed elements are available.  What you want to do is pushing the limits of typical usage, combining may different features, and you may need to get creative.  Start by figuring out the individual elements.  (cont'd)

Comment: How to accomplish this whole task is probably beyond the intended scope of a question, but if you run into difficulty with a piece of it, that problem is likely in-scope and could be a good dedicated question.

Comment: fixer1234 how do I give you an acknowledgement?  You have my enduring thanks.

Comment: Does that mean you figured it out?  If so, congrats!  This general kind of problem comes up every now and then.  If you figured it out, consider posting an answer explaining how you did it.  Chances are the next person won't have exactly the same requirement, but some details of your solution would likely give them the concepts they need.